# Two dimensional array in Twig

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony, twig

I have satellite images stored in a mysql database. The table has attributes latitude,longitude. I want to send them to the twig and display as a map, my php controller looks like this.

```
public function highlightAction()
{
    $highlighted=$this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:satelliteImage')
        ->findAll();

    $images = array();
    foreach ($highlighted as $key => $high) {
        $images[$key] = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($high->getImage()));
    }

    return $this->render('satelliteImages/highlighted.html.twig',array(
        'highlighted' => $highlighted,
        'images' => $images

    ));

}
```

My twig code is this:

```
    <tbody>
    {% for key,high in highlighted %}
        <tr>
            <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ images[key] }}" />

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

I am displaying the images as a vertical array. Any suggestions, I might need to display them as a map.
A two dimensional array in twig?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What is your problem ? What does mean "display as a map" ?

Comment: I have 12 satellite images in the database. When they are arranged as a 3x4 array they would form a map.(since they are parts of one big area). Right now I'm only able to display them as a vertical list.....I do not have much knowledge on php or twig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for key in 0..2  %}
        <tr>
            {% for key in 0..3 %}
                <td>
                    <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,
                        {{ images[loop.parent.key*4 + key] }}" />
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Read the [Twig for documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks.It worked perfectly. However say I don't know the size of the array and its like 100 images. I only know the difference between each latitude and longitude. (say 0.00875) Any idea on how to display a similar map using the two attributes latitude and longitude?